# Reflection: Get properties/fields from individual elements of a List<>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I'm sorry in advance for the mess you're about to read, because I'm not 100% sure what I'm searching for.

I have created an entire UI system that automatically grabs a list of properties from various scripts/components on GameObjects (Unity) and creates a fitting UI input variant for them (for example, float gets a single line, Vector3 gets 3 lines, color gets something else etc.).

What goes into UI input fields creation is a Component (that we want to look into), while individual created UI inputs store this Component and Property Name. So when input changes in one of input fields, it does SetValue on Property of a Component. Now I have also created a variant where we peak into a Class of a property and basically list Property's Properties, so the UI input stores Component, Property Name, and subProperty's Name and modifies properties as such. All this works well.

So, now I hit a brick wall with Lists. I would like to treat individual elements of a list as properties so that I could pass them into my preexisting UI scheme.

**tl;dr** Does List<> treat it's individual elements as Properties, Fields or does it depend on the situation? How do I get these properties, fields or their respective names from this list in order to use them with my mess of an UI system? 0 work for me means treating individual elements of List as properties.

**----------------------------
EDIT----------------------------**

Again I am sorry for this mess of a question. It is a mixture of confused theory and description of an existing situation that I am trying to shoehorn into my already existing project (which is a bit too over the place to be easily reduced to an example).

If anyone grasped what I was asking for, the single easiest solution was to create a property which prior to listing was equated to an element of a list.

Example looks something like this:

```
public List<MyCustomClass> myCustomList;
[Listable("ForEdit")]
public myCustomClass myCustomPropertyForEdit
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And before withdrawing properties of myCustomPropertyForEdit's class (myCustomClass) I would simply do:

```
myCustomPropertyForEdit = myCustomList[0]; //or whatever index is in question
```

Then later on I would do reflection on "myCustomPropertyForEdit" instead of myCustomList. I highly doubt this will ever help anyone because it touches more onto how I built methods for listing properties into my UI, but there it is just in case.

Comment: Your question is kinda vague, but _"Does List<> treat it's individual elements as Properties, Fields or does it depend on the situation?"_ No, they count as elements in a collection.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can suggest you something. Currently, it's hard to say what to do.

Comment: Read this, it should help. https://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: `I would like to treat individual elements of a list as properties so that I could pass them into my preexisting UI scheme` - some code would help us understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List stores references to objects, by providing an index you get a standard object reference, which you can proceed to query using reflection (do not do it against the list itself as you will get methods of the List class, and notthing related to what the list contains)

Comment: Accepting as solution, with addition that I provided a fix for my situation in edit on OP.

Comment: @MrQuestions Answers are answers and belong as an answer, not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

take for  example:

```
public Class Tree
{
    public int branches;

    public Tree(int branch)
    {
        branches=branch;
    }
}

List<Tree> trees = new List<Tree>();
trees.Add(new Tree(3));
```

now my list has one element at index 0;

so i can do `trees[0].branches`;

to access the fields/props of an element in trees.

list is not an array, it holds the actual item, allowing you to reference, not just the object but also its own unique variables. as long as they are public in the class.